# Question about translating input/output ODE to state space representation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

It is well known that a differential equation (that models an input/output behavior of single input) for an LTI system, of the form

$$b_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1} y(t)}{d t^n} + ... + b_1\frac{d y(t)}{d t} + b_0y(t) = u(t)$$

can be translated into the state space:

$$ \mathbf{\dot{x}}(t) = A\mathbf{x}(t) + B\mathbf{u}(t)$$

$$ y(t) = C\mathbf{x}(t) + D\mathbf{u}(t)$$

with $A$,$B$, $C$, $D$, real matrices of appropriate sizes

**however my question is**

If I have a more general equation such as:

$$b_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1} y(t)}{d t^n} + ... + b_1\frac{d y(t)}{d t} + b_0y(t) = a_{m-1}\frac{d^{m-1} u(t)}{d t^{m-1}} + ... + a_1\frac{d u(t)}{d t} + a_0u(t)$$

**¿Can I translate this into the state space equation?**

If so, could you point me to bibliography where I can see this.

The reason why I'm asking this, is because I asked Chat GPT what was the most general differential equation that models an LTI system and it's answer was this:

[image: Chat GPT answer]

OF course I then asked why was that the most general equation and where did it found it, it told me that it can't say what was it's source. I've been looking at books on control theory and I can't find that general form that GPT said, only the first one.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is realization. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509870/i-need-help-to-convert-this-dynamic-system-in-a-space-state-model/4510366#4510366) for an example. There are a number of examples on the exchange.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: This approach works for proper systems, that is, $n \ge m$.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks for the info, but where can I see that approach? any bibliography or books where they use this approach? al book's I've consulted have the only one output without the derivatives

Comment: This has been asked many times here. Please search a little bit before asking.

Comment: @KBS Could you point me to a question that asks the same as mine? everyone in the comments are saying that it's a well known result without actual bibliography or links. Edit. I did search for similar questions and found nothing, that's why I asked this question

Comment: @CésarVB Does [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4411967/76466) help?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen it does help, thank you! I will try to generalize it to an arbitrary input derivative although it does not seem immediate

Comment: Check this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4510366/532783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask for the general solution and an explicit reference: This problem was solved by Ülle Kotta in the paper

Kotta, Ü. "Removing input derivatives in generalized state-space systems: a linear algebraic approach." 1998 4th International Conference on Actual Problems of Electronic Instrument Engineering Proceedings. APEIE-98 (Cat. No. 98EX179). IEEE, 1998.

There, a general nonlinear system with finite but arbitrary number of input derivatives is considered and necessary and sufficient conditions are given for the existence of a generalized state transformation such that the transformed system depends only on (new) state variables and inputs without derivative.

A corrolary of this result is given as Corollary 2 in the paper for linear systems of the form

$$
\dot{x}=Fx+G_1u+\dots+G_{\alpha+1}u^{(\alpha)}
$$

where $u^{(\alpha)}$ is the $\alpha$-th derivative of $u$. Then there always exists a state transformation of the form

$$
z=Px+R_1u+\dots+R_{\alpha}u^{(\alpha-1)}
$$

where $P$ is an invertible matrix such that

$$
\dot{z}=\widetilde{F}z+\widetilde{G}u
$$

See also the references given in that paper, i.e.

- Delaleau, E., & Respondek, W. (1992, December). Removing input derivatives and lowering their orders in generalized state-space representations. In [1992] Proceedings of the 31st IEEE Conference on Decision and Control (pp. 3663-3668). IEEE.
- Di Benedetto, M. D., Grizzle, J. W., & Moog, C. H. (1989). Rank invariants of nonlinear systems. SIAM journal on control and optimization, 27(3), 658-672.
- Fliess, M. (1990). Some basic structural properties of generalized linear systems. Systems & Control Letters, 15(5), 391-396.
- Pottle, C. (1966). State-space techniques for general active network analysis. System Analysis by Digital Computers.

Comment: Thank you! this really helps me!, I'm a newbie to control theory and I've consulted  many books with different approaches and diffrent justifications to what originates the famous SSR $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$ that it's overwhelming. This clears things more!